# Replace output text from textbox in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I replace output text in html5.

For example, user Input this text: My name is Toni.

I want to replace the output text: "Toni" to Ani, for example, output, become: "My name is Ani".

This is my code:

```html
<title>textBoxes.html</title>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  // from textBoxes.html
  function repleace(){
  var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");
  var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
  var name = txtName.value;
  if(name == "toni"){
  name = "ani";
  }
  txtOutput.value = name;
  }
 </script>
 <link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "textBoxes.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Text Box Input and Output</h1>
 <form action = "">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Type your name: </label>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "txtName" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "GO"
    onclick = "repleace()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "txtOutput" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

this code just Replace text when I input text: Toni, but when I input: My name is Toni. Cant replace text, Toni.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Javascript build in function replace:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

This will search the string and only replace the matching part with the new one.

Explanation why you code is not working:

You are checking if the textbox value is equal to toni and if so replace the whole string with ani.

Answer (score 0):

Use Replace function.

name.replace("toni", "Ani");